# javascript add or replace an object by property check inside another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to add or replace an object inside another array.

```
var arr = [
  {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
  {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"},
]
```

here here is an new object:

```
var mynewObject = {uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc"};
```

i am already doing it like:

```
function addOrReplace (arr, object) {
  var index = arr.findIndex(x => object.uid === x.uid);
  if (-1 === index) {
    arr.push(object);
  } else {
    arr[index] = object;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

but this is very ugly.
is there any way to do it in one line or two?

the original array should remain an array, and the new object should be checked only by property `uid`.

Comment: Why is it ugly? You need a conditional of some kind

Comment: Questions about refactoring or optimizing working code are better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . This site is for fixing code that isn't working as expected

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from just storing them in an object by uid? `arr[object.uid] = object`. If you are just going to replace it or make it, that should work.

Answer (score 6):

To achieve the same functionality, yet make it a more condense one-liner, run [**Array#findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and assign its result to the unused parameter `idx` of the function *(effectively overwriting its value, which is `undefined` by default, or the value, with which the function was called)*, then use a simple [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to modify the existing object or add to the array and finally return the modified array.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu" },
  { uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu" },
]
const mynewObject1 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

const arr2 = [
  { uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu" },
]
const mynewObject2 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

const arr3 = []
const mynewObject3 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

function addOrReplace (arr, obj, idx) {
  return (idx = arr.findIndex(x => obj.uid === x.uid) > -1 ? arr[idx] = obj : arr.push(obj)), arr;
}

console.log(addOrReplace(arr1, mynewObject1));
console.log(addOrReplace(arr2, mynewObject2));
console.log(addOrReplace(arr3, mynewObject3));
```

Or a bit more concise if you don't need to return the array:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu" },
  { uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu" },
]
const mynewObject1 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

const arr2 = [
  { uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu" },
]
const mynewObject2 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

const arr3 = []
const mynewObject3 = { uid: 1, name: "newBlabla", description: "newDesc" };

function addOrReplace (arr, obj, idx) {
  idx = arr.findIndex(x => obj.uid === x.uid) > -1 ? arr[idx] = obj : arr.push(obj);
}

addOrReplace(arr1, mynewObject1)
console.log(arr1);

addOrReplace(arr2, mynewObject2)
console.log(arr2);

addOrReplace(arr3, mynewObject3)
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: When need to add a new object to the array the function returns the new length of the array instead of the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
const addOrReplace = (arr, obj) => {
    arr = arr.filter(el => el.uid !== obj.uid);
    arr.push(obj)
    return arr;
}
```